# How I can add data attribute into Hyperlink?

Tags: javascript

How to add multiple options from the selection box to the data attribute `data-clc` in the hyperlink?

Working in textarea but `TestLink` hyperlink not working.

```js
 $("#selection").change(function() {
   $('#selected').html(' ');
   $("#selection option:selected").each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     if ($this.length) {
       var selText = $this.text();
       console.log(selText);
       $('#selected').append(selText + ', ');
       $('#comeMan').attr('data-bid', selText);
     }
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" style="width:200px;" id="selection" name="fm_fields[]">
    <option value="90" selected>Collection1</option>
    <option value="91" selected>Collection2</option>
    <option value="92">Collection3</option>
    <option value="93">Collection4</option>
    <option value="94">Collection5</option>
    <option value="95">Collection6</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="comeMan" data-clc="">TestLink</a>
  <textarea id="selected" rows="1" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

**Goal**

For example:
`<a href="#" 
id="comeMan" data-clc=" Collection2,Collection3,Collection4">TestLink</a>`

Comment: Please do not post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and make your question meaningless. Just include your code in a "snippet", right here in your question, by clicking the "snippet" icon on the new question toolbar.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Is this mandatory? Maybe I don't like it? Why are you changing without my permission? Also you're not a moderator or staff.

Comment: As you get more familiar with Stack Overflow, you will learn how the platform works. As you gain reputation, you will gain certain moderator privileges as I have. The ability to edit other people's questions and answers are some of those privileges, as are the abilities to close and delete questions. There is no benefit to posting your code to a 3rd party site for the reasons I mentioned and while it's not "mandatory", we discourage it.

Comment: For a bit more explanation, by posting your executable code here, it makes it simple for us to copy that over into our answer (as I have done) and better respond to your question.

Comment: I understand @ScottMarcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than build up a string of the selected items, you can just set the attribute to the `value` (`val()` in JQuery) of the `select` element.

Also, to more easily work with `data-` attributes, JQuery provides the [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method (used below);

```js
$("#selection").change(function() {
   $('#comeMan').data('clc',  $('#selection').val());
   console.log( $('#comeMan').data('clc'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple style="width:200px;" id="selection" name="fm_fields[]">
    <option value="90">Collection1</option>
    <option value="91">Collection2</option>
    <option value="92">Collection3</option>
    <option value="93">Collection4</option>
    <option value="94">Collection5</option>
    <option value="95">Collection6</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="comeMan">TestLink</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!